# Converting answers to comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, moderation

I've just noticed a feature that I was not aware of.

If you look at [this question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/2338/136), there are a couple of answers that were converted to comments. It's the first time that I see something like that, how can it be done? Is it something that only moderators can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is a moderator only privilege to my knowledge. If you are not a moderator you can flag an answer as "not an answer" and a moderator will either delete it or convert it to a comment if appropriate.